# Diplay filter with ip destination and port dest: what is wrong?

Tags: wireshark

What is wrong with the display filter?

```
tshark -r "semAtaques.pcap" -Tfields -e frame.time_epoch -e tcp.window_size_value -e ip.dst -Y "ip.dst == 192.168.91.5" -e tcp.port eq 80 >> winTime_10Abril_SemAtaques.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tshark -r "slowloris.pcap" -Tfields -e frame.time_epoch -e tcp.window_size_value -Y "ip.dst==192.168.91.5 && tcp.dstport==80" >> winTime_10Abril_SemAtaques.txt
```